# oAuth server response format

Tags: api, oauth, json-api, responseformat

I am using http://jsonapi.org as a the format for the responses of my api. I am however a little puzzled how to correctly respond to a request for an access token.

As far as I am aware, from the oAuth side I need to return the following:

```
{
  "access_token": "abc1234...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

From the jsonapi docs I got that every request needs to return a `resource object`. And every `resource object` needs a data element with type and id.

However I feel this is not correct for the oAuth token request. Please help me how to do this correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in the jsonapi forum and tyler kellen provided a very good answer (http://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/json-api-response-format-for-non-resource-data-like-oauth-token/74). I settled for this now:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "data": {
    "id": "Qcg6yI1a5qCxXgKWtSAbZ2MIHFChHAq0Vc1Lo4TX",
    "type": "token",
    "attributes": {
      "access_token": "Qcg6yI1a5qCxXgKWtSAbZ2MIHFChHAq0Vc1Lo4TX",
      "token_type": "Bearer",
      "expires_in": 3600
    }
  }
}
```